# Django - Not able to add ForeignKey or OneToOneField to User model

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, migration

I have a Profile model in which I am creating a OneToOneField to User Model. Code:

```
user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user', null=True)
```

I am able to run makemigrations but on running migrate, I get the following error.

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user'

Comment: probably you have entered `user` as default value when migrating. So you need to remove your last migration file and put `ForeignKey(...,default=None)` in the model field

Comment: If you have a new question ask a new question, don't totally edit your previous one as it invalidates any effort/answer other users have put in to it

Answer (score 0):

Change you related_name to "custom_user" or something else than "user"